# Sum of producst of subsums of (nodes with the same id) by a matching price

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I add all the nodes' attributes which have the same index atrribute. I multiply this sum by a particular number (extracted from a secontary xml) and I have the step_1 product. I repeat the proceedure multiplying each time by a different particular number, and I add the new product to the product of the previous step and so on up to the last node.  But in each step of the loop the sum functions looses the runningsum keeping only the current product. I would appreciate any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="koinohrista.xsl"?>
 <Features>
  <Feature code="a" price="1"></Feature>
  <Feature code="a" price="2"></Feature>
  <Feature code="b" price="3"></Feature>
  <Feature code="b" price="4"></Feature>
  <Feature code="c" price="5"></Feature>
 </Features>
```

The secondary xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hiliosta.xsl"?>
 <Features>
  <Feature name="a1" koinoh="10" elev="20" heat="30"></Feature>
 </Features>
```

The xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:variable name="Inventory" select="document('C:\Kapopoulos\Inventory.xml')"/>   
 <xsl:key name="KeyCode" match="Feature" use="@code"/>
 <xsl:template match="Features">
  <xsl:call-template name="sum">
   <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="Feature"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="0"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>
  <!-- Sum Function -->
 <xsl:template name="sum">
  <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
  <xsl:param name="sum"/>
  <xsl:variable name="curr" select="$nodes[1]"/>
$sum1 = <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/><br/> <!-- for view reasons -->
     <table>
  <xsl:for-each select="Feature[generate-id() = generate-id(key('KeyCode',@code)[1])]">   
  <xsl:sort select="@code" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:if test="$curr"> 
Step1 = <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/> ||| <!-- for view reasons -->
     <xsl:variable name="attrName">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@code='a' or @code='c' or @code='d'">koinoh</xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="@code='b'">elev</xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="@code='e'">heat</xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:variable name="runningsum" select="$sum + sum(key('KeyCode',@code)/@price) 
     * $Inventory/*/Feature[@name='a1']/@*[name()=$attrName] div sum($Inventory//Feature/@*[name()=$attrName])"/> 
RunSum2 = <xsl:value-of select="$runningsum"/><br/> <!-- for view reasons -->
    <xsl:call-template name="sum">
     <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[position() &gt; 1]"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$runningsum"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:if test="not($curr)"> Final= 
    <xsl:value-of select="$sum"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </table> 
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired calculation steps and output

```
1) SumOfPrice for @code="a" : 1+2=3
2) ProductOfSum : 3 * "koinoh"=3*10=30
3) RunningSum = 30
4) SumOfPrice for @code="b" : 3+4=7
5) ProductOfSum : 7 * "@elev"=7*20=140
6) RunningSum = 30+140=170
7) SumOfPrice for @code="c" : 5
8) ProductOfSum : 5 * "@heat" = 5*30=150
6) RunningSum = 30+140+150=320
DesiredOutput = 320
```

Comment: P{lease edit your question and add the expected result.

Comment: Provided corrections for mr Michael comment

Comment: Is that the entire output you want, a single number (320)?

Comment: Exactly. Just a single number (320)

Comment: Mr michael.hor thank you very much. One more question:

Comment: Mr michael.hor thank you very much for you answer. One more question if you please: your code is restricted only into @name='a1'. I try to use this code in a loop, where I provide your "function" in each step of the loop with the next @name=a2 etc, getting your $balance price for each Feature/@name of the secondary Inventrory.xml. Since the inventory is used as a variable I cannot manage to manipulate it in an xsl:for-each statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could define the `inventory` variable as `document($path-to-inventory)/Features` and then use it as `$inventory/Feature[@name='a1']/@koinoh` or  `$inventory/Feature[@name='a2']/@koinoh` and so on. But this is not described in your question so I am not sure how exactly it's supposed to work.

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

To get only the final result of 320, you could skip the grouping part and just process each individual `Feature` on its own. However, it might be useful to minimize the lookups to the "Inventory" document, so let's keep the grouping:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-inventory">C:\Kapopoulos\Inventory.xml</xsl:param>
<xsl:variable name="inventory" select="document($path-to-inventory)/Features/Feature[@name='a1']"/>

<xsl:key name="feature-by-code" match="Feature" use="@code" />

<xsl:template match="/Features">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="summarize">
            <!-- select distinct codes only -->
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="Feature[count(. | key('feature-by-code', @code)[1]) = 1]"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="summarize">
    <xsl:param name="items" select="/.."/>
    <xsl:param name="balance" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$items">
            <xsl:variable name="code" select="$items[1]/@code" />
            <xsl:variable name="sum-price" select="sum(key('feature-by-code', $code)/@price)" />
            <xsl:variable name="factor">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$code='a'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$inventory/@koinoh" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$code='b'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$inventory/@elev" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$code='c'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$inventory/@heat" />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="product" select="$sum-price * $factor" />
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="summarize">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="balance" select="$balance + $product"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$balance" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```